# Can neural networks, predict a vector using a larger vector as input? If yes how?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, python

Apologies if this is considered obsolete but I am fairly new in using Neural Networks for time series. Supposing we do not want to use an LSTM for predicting the sequence, how would we handle this case in Python :

Having a large vector as input containing values taken every minute (so it is a time series), and the output Y is a series of a day's worth of predictions (1440 values).

My goal is to do this prediction with a neural network in python. I would like to do it without the use of an LSTM.

All the above mean that the prediction vector length is fixed, the input vector length is fixed( if you have a suggestion that works with non-fixed INPUT length that is very acceptable as well).

My uncertainty is how to make the output giving a vector of my desired length, cause most of the other examples i have found that the output was bigger than length 1 was for multilabel classification which is not what I am looking for. I think what I am looking can be considered as neural network regression for multiple time steps.

Please let me know if something is unclear or more information are required. Thank you!